# Is an iPad screen an Optical Prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light

One day, I noticed that sometimes, when there is an iPad right below a light, such as a chandelier, when viewed from an angle, one can see what looks like a spectra of colors. Is the iPad screen acting like a optical prism and why?

Answer (score 0):

You might have observed a phenomenon called [Thin-film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference). An iPad has thin films layers in its construction.

Comment: I think the phenomenon is different. I have seen thin film interference on iPads before and this different. The iPad has a spectrum instead

Comment: @TanMath: thin film interference has a spectrum too. My first thought when reading this question was *thin film interference*. I believe the answer is correct.

Comment: @Gert but the spectrum I see is more discrete. Thin film interference does not seem to have discrete spectrum

Comment: @TanMath: it probably isn't but viewed with the naked eye that's so *subjective* it isn't worth talking about.